# SQL weird error : Error converting value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

When I do

```
SELECT RecTime, CAST(ID as nvarchar(MAX)) AS Col, InitialValue FROM [dbo].[Changes]
```

I've got no errors

When I do

```
SELECT RecTime, Col, InitialValue FROM [dbo].[XDeltaIntervals]
```

I've got no errors

But when I do

```
SELECT RecTime, CAST(ID as nvarchar(MAX)) AS Col, InitialValue 
FROM [dbo].[Changes]
        UNION ALL
   SELECT RecTime, Col, InitialValue FROM [dbo].[XDeltaIntervals]
```

Col from XDeltaIntervals is nvarchar(MAX)

I've got Error Message :

> Message 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Error converting value nvarchar
>   "davl> 40" to the data type bit. Attention! NULL is excluded in the
>   aggregate, or other operations SET.

davl> 40 is Col from XDeltaIntervals and it's nvarchar and I can't understand where I'm trying to convert it to bit :S

How can I avoid this request to convert Col from second part of union to bit ?

Comment: What type is `Changes.InitialValue`? If it is a bit type, you have your answer.

Comment: @Bjorkey what is the type of the Col column?

Comment: Which column is `bit` in your query? There can't possibly be any attempt to convert the `Col` from the second half into `bit` unless you have provided us with incomplete query and thus the problem is related to some other part of the actual query you were running when you got the error (and the warning for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attention! NULL is excluded in the aggregate, or other operations SET.` doesn't appear to have any correlation to the query you have shown. Are either of these Views?

If so try `EXEC sp_refreshview 'dbo.XDeltaIntervals'`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reversing the order of the UNION?

```
SELECT RecTime, Col, InitialValue
FROM [dbo].[XDeltaIntervals] 
UNION ALL
SELECT RecTime, CAST(ID as nvarchar(MAX)) AS Col, InitialValue
FROM [dbo].[Changes]
```

The data types of the resulting set are based on the values from the first SELECT statement.

Comment: This isn't true. `select 'x' UNION ALL SELECT 1` gives `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int.` it goes off data type precedence.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the > character in the actual column-name for "col" is being interpreted as an operator.  What if you wrap the column-name in brackets [].

Comment: But if that was the case, shouldn't it also break when that particular select is run alone?

Comment: Don't know -- it depends on where/when the problem is occuring, if that is the problem --  but it wouldn't hurt to surround in [] the column-name with an ">" in it -- and if that has no benefit then I'd remove the ">" from the column name.